# How would you explain Hierarchical Bayesian modeling?

Tags: bayesian, modeling, hierarchical-bayesian

To the widest audience ? The people I have to present some of my models are not statisticians and I don't have a simple way to put it or simple self-explanatory graphs.

Comment: Assuming you're talking about Bayesian priors that have hyperparameters (thus forming a model hierarchy), perhaps [this baseball model](http://doingbayesiandataanalysis.blogspot.com/2012/11/shrinkage-in-multi-level-hierarchical.html) example might do?

Comment: You could maybe get some ideas from [here](https://sites.google.com/site/simplebayes/home/pycon-2013). This does not focus so much on hierarchical models but Bayesian inference in general, which I assume you need to ease into first. Otherwise I find that [the German tank problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem) is a good example to show non-Bayesians.